# Unexpected output when creating a List of Lists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> largeGroupPositions(String S) {
        //int k=0;
        List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<List<Integer>> l2 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        int n = S.length();

        int count =1, i1=0, i2=0;
        for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
            if(S.charAt(i)==S.charAt(i-1)){
                count++;

            }else{
                i2 = i-1;
                if(count>=3){
                    l1.add(i1);
                    l1.add(i2);
                    l2.add(l1);


                }

                count =1;
                i1=i;
            }
        }

        return l2;

    }
}
```

I need this output `[[3,5],[6,9],[12,14]]`, But i am getting `[[3,5,6,9,12,14],[3,5,6,9,12,14],[3,5,6,9,12,14]]`, If i uses l1.clear() in else part then the changes is occuring in l2 also

Comment: did you debugged?

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3788176)

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176)

Comment: The problem is that you are reusing `l1`. Move the declaration of `l1` inside the `if(count>=3)` conditional.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on how to debug your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all the integers to the same inner list (the one that you create at the start of your method with the statement `List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();`).

You should create a new `List` before adding elements to it:

```
for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
    if(S.charAt(i)==S.charAt(i-1)) {
        count++;
    } else {
        i2 = i-1;
        if(count>=3) {
            List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            l1.add(i1);
            l1.add(i2);
            l2.add(l1);
        }

        count =1;
        i1=i;
    }
}
```

Comment: @rishabh_95 there is literally no other way, because you cannot reuse the same list instance. Why do you think you can't create lists like this?

Comment: @rishabh_95 Did you notice that I moved the `List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();` statement? What do you mean by `i can't create new list`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you made your cache array (List l1 = new ArrayList();) global.

So every time you add, you add to the same array. And you can't just clear it, since you add it to l2, clearing l1 also clears the array as it is in l2.

The reason is that when you add l1 to l2, it doesn't copy the values of l1 into l2, rather what it does is add the *pointer (or reference) of l1 into l2*. So it really has only one backing array.

Try something like this:

```
class Solution {
public List<List<Integer>> largeGroupPositions(String S) {
//int k=0;

List<List<Integer>> l2 = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
int n = S.length();

int count =1, i1=0, i2=0;
for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if(S.charAt(i)==S.charAt(i-1)){
        count++;

    }else{
        i2 = i-1;

        if(count>=3){
            List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            l1.add(i1);
            l1.add(i2);
            l2.add(l1);


        }

        count =1;
        i1=i;
    }
}

return l2;

}
```